# Use AddRange for a new List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, addrange

**How to: Use AddRange for a List**

```
List<string> list = 
    new List<string>().AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

It is a variable which is declared globally - what is my mistake?

The error is equal to

> Converting from string to void is not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply change your code to this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8));
```

Answer (score 7):

cause `AddRange` return type is void, not  `List<string>`.

And, as error states, you can't assign (=) a `void` to a `List<string>`

You can just do

```
List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to dow it in two steps:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8));
```

`AddRange` does not return the list, so you need to "get the instance first" or directly initialize it like HABJAN suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your statement:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8));
```

Or, if you want to do it in 1 step:

```
List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
```